# 編集モードでセルを削除したとき、別のメソッドを呼び出したい (UITableViewDelegate)

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift3, uitableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        myAray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        print("Hello World")
    }
}
```

上記のようにデリゲートメソッドを書いた場合、
スワイプして編集モードの削除をタップすることでセルの削除はされるのですが
Hello Worldと出力はされておりません。
どのようにすれば定義したメソッドを呼び出すことができるのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: あなたが掲載されたコードをそのまま`UITableView`を表示するview controllerに貼り付けて試してみましたが、編集モードでの削除でもスワイプによる削除でも **Hello World** がデバッグコンソールに表示されました。(ただし、「セルの削除はされる」ようには見えないですが。)あなたが体験している状況を再現するに必要十分なコード全体を掲載していただけないでしょうか？

Comment: コンソール表示できたということで、他の削除系メソッドを改めて調べてみると干渉している部分があったので修正すると私もコンソール表示することができました。ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Comment: ご回答の投稿ありがとうございます。同じようなことで悩んでいる方は多そうです。少し時間を置かないといけませんが、ご自分の回答にも「承認」の操作ができますので、ぜひ後ほどチェックしてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let deleteButton: UITableViewRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "削除") { (action, index) -> Void in
        self.myAray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
    deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    return [deleteButton]
}
```

削除に関する他のメソッドを見てみると、上記コードが干渉していたので
メソッドの呼び出しができていなかったようでした。
お手数をおかけしました。